# Django - redirect reverse() with slug and kwargs

Tags: python, django

project URLS.py

```
path('<slug:slug>/', include('orgs.urls')),
```

app URLS.py

```
path('donate/', views.org_site_view, name='org_donate', kwargs=dict(page='donate')),
```

Which looks like :  mysite.org/samporg/donate
Where samporg is the slug variable.

I am trying to redirect to a Success Page using the same Donate View 'org_donate' .

In view I have tried :

```
return redirect(reverse('org_donate', slug='samporg', kwargs={'page': 'donate_success'}))

return redirect(reverse('org_donate', kwargs={'page':'donate_success'}))

return redirect('org_donate', slug='samporg', kwargs={'page':'donate_success'})

return redirect('org_donate', kwargs={'slug':'samporg','page':'donate_success'})
```

None work. All throw Argument or Reverse errors

```
Reverse for 'org_donate' with keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'slug': 'samporg', 'page': 'donate_success'}}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/donate\\/$']
```

Comment: But what is that ` 'page': 'donate_success'` supposed to be doing in the reverse call? Your URL doesn't take any such parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think the **`path()`** function will accept **`kwargs`** as an argument.So, remove it

```
# app/urls.py
path('donate/', views.org_site_view, name='org_donate'),
```

and in your views, it should be as,

```
return redirect('org_donate', kwargs={'slug':'samporg'})
```

Comment: i ended up using a different solution, but for any future dev : Path *will* accept kwargs like this within the URLS :  path('about/', views.org_site_view, name='org_about', kwargs=dict(page='about'))